# How do I handle a variable number of arguments passed to a function in Racket?

Tags: list, arguments, scheme, racket, variadic-functions

I like creating functions which take an unlimited number of arguments, and being able to deal with them as a list. It's been useful to me when creating binary trees & I'm using it for a variation on the nearest-neighbor algorithm right now. My method, however, is really horrible: since I can't think of a way to iterate over an improper list (which may well be improper & degenerate), I tried using various list functions to force the improper list into list form.

This is my best attempt in a simple function to determine difference between map-nodes (works, just not sure why it works):

```
(define distance-between
  (lambda xs
    (let ([input-list (list* xs null)])
      (letrec 
          ([f (lambda (xs acc)
               (if (null? (cdr xs))
                   acc
                   (f (cdr xs) 
                      (+ (abs (- (map-node-x (car xs)) 
                                 (map-node-x (cadr xs))))
                         (abs (- (map-node-y (car xs)) 
                                 (map-node-y (cadr xs))))
                         acc))))])                   
       (f (car input-list) 0)))))
```

As you can see, it's an ugly solution and involves some of what seems like magic to me - why is the improper list coerced into list form when I include it in a list*? (note: this sentence is misleading, this does not occur).

I'd rather have a pretty solution and no magic. Can anyone help?

For example a typical input would be:

```
(distance-between (map-node 1 2) (map-node 2 3) (map-node 3 4))
```

with the expected result:

```
4
```

(a distance of 2 between map-node (a) and m-n (b), plus a distance of 2 between map-node (b) and map-node (c)).

Alternatively one might simply input:

```
(distance-between (map-node 1 2) (map-node 2 2))
```

and get an answer of:

```
1
```

If I attempted this on the raw input, without my (let ([input-list...])...) statement, it would cause an error as (? not actually sure why given response to this question).

The function works as expected.

Comment: Under what circumstances might you be dealing with an improper list? Variadic argument lists are always proper. Also, you should describe what your function should do, with sample inputs and outputs.

Comment: I'm not sure what a Variadic argument list is (other than, perhaps, this). I'm basing the idea that these lists are improper off some other answers on stack overflow, and the fact that the unprocessed list xs isn't treated as a list by any other function - they throw errors saying that it is not a list. Also, it doesn't automatically end in null, which is what I think all Lisps use as the basis for their lists. I will describe what my function does do now, however it works exactly as intended.

Comment: Essentially my confusion arises from the fact that when I try to use list functions such as (length xs) on the raw input of the...variadic argument list? They raise errors.

Comment: In the example the problem is not the function, it's the _way you're calling it_. It should be: `(define dist (distance-between (map-node 1 2) (map-node 2 3) (map-node 3 4)))`

Comment: Oops. Sorry, that was a typo. That's not how I've typically been calling it. However you were totally correct that the problem lay elsewhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's nothing improper about the list received as a variadic argument list (meaning: variable number of arguments). For example:

```
(define test-list
  (lambda xs
    (length xs))) ; xs is a normal list, use it like any other list

(test-list 1 2 3 4)
=> 4
```

In the above example, the `xs` parameter is a normal, plain, vanilla list, there's nothing improper about it. You can iterate over it as you would over any other list. There's no need to `car` it, it's already a list! Also, notice that the same function can be written like this:

```
(define (test-list . xs)
  (length xs))   ; xs is a normal list, use it like any other list
```

Just for reference: an improper list is one that does *not* end with the null list. For example: `'(1 2 3 . 4)`. Again, that's not how a variadic argument list looks.

Comment: I find this really interesting because this is what I saw myself, however list functions such as (length xs) refused to work on the input I used.

Comment: @JamesDuval then the problem is with the input, not with the way variadic argument lists work

Comment: @JamesDuval you should post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I also don't understand how your variadic argument list could be improper.

But to answer your original question (how to iterate over a possibly improper list, somewhat more elegantly), here is one way using `match`:

```
#lang racket

(define (properly-sum-improper-list xs)
  (let loop ([acc 0]
             [xs xs])
    (match xs
      [(list) acc]
      [(cons x more) (loop (+ acc x) more)]
      [x (+ acc x)]))) ;last item of improper list

(require rackunit)
(check-equal? (properly-sum-improper-list '(1 2 3 4))   10)
(check-equal? (properly-sum-improper-list '(1 2 3 . 4)) 10)
```

However needing to do this, at all, is probably an indication you want to fix or change something else.

Comment: > needing to do this, at all, is probably an indication you want to fix or change something else. -- absolutely agreed. I completely misunderstood where the problem lay and was able to fix it quickly once the people here on stack overflow set me straight!

Comment: When I started to learn Racket (my first real Lisp) a few years ago, "proper" vs. "improper" lists was one of those things that felt like a mysterious distinction without a difference. IME it's an odd corner where you sometimes want to go, but are more likely to find yourself by accident.

Answer (score 4):

Your list is not improper. When your argument is not a pair, like `(lambda xs body ...)` or `(define (fun . xs) body ...)` all your arguments gets slurped into a list. Eg.. `(fun 1 2 3)` would make xs `'(1 2 3)`. Doing `(list* '(1 2 3) '())` makes `'((1 2 3)` which you undo right away by calling your loop with `car` which makes it `'(1 2 3)` again.

Other than that your procedure works as intended.  You might clean up your procedure a little, but since there is no list comprehensions that glides over a list folding over the two next elements it won't become much smaller. Below is basically the same code, but abstracting out the procedure that does *the work* (which if existed a  foldl-pair you could have used) and with a `named let` as a iterator loop (which is syntactic sugar for a letrec+call).

```
(define (distance-between e1 . lst)
  (define (add-diff-acc e1 e2 acc)
    (+ (abs (- (map-node-x e1) (map-node-x e2)))
       (abs (- (map-node-y e1) (map-node-y e2)))
       acc))

  (let iterate ((e1 e1) (lst lst) (acc 0))
    (if (pair? lst)
        (let ((e2 (car lst)))
          (iterate e2 (cdr lst) (add-diff-acc e1 e2 acc)))
        acc)))
```

**EDIT: About syntax sugar, `named let` and `letrec`.**

```
(let ((x 10) (y 19)) 
  body)
```

is syntactic sugar for a anonymous procedure call

```
((lambda (x y) 
    body) 
  10 19)
```

A `named let` is just giving that procedure a name, though as if by `letrec`, making a *recursive* binding. you call it with the name you give and the arguments will be what you supply instead of the initial value in the let. I'm used to them and prefer them today. It might take some time to get used to though.

Most of the code we write is syntactic sugar for some lower level stuff. The macros are nested so that your `letrec` form *could* get reduced down lambdas eventually. The whole procedure without syntactic sugar would look like this:

```
(define distance-between 
  (lambda (e1 . lst)
    ((lambda (add-diff-acc)
       ((lambda (iterate e1 lst acc) ; emulate Y to substitute `letrec`
          (iterate iterate e1 lst acc))
        (lambda (iterate e1 lst acc)
          (if (pair? lst)
              ((lambda (e2)
                 (iterate iterate e2 (cdr lst) (add-diff-acc e1 e2 acc)))
               (car lst))
              acc))
        e1 lst 0))
     (lambda (e1 e2 acc)
       (+ (abs (- (map-node-x e1) (map-node-x e2)))
          (abs (- (map-node-y e1) (map-node-y e2)))
          acc)))))
```

Comment: I appreciate the refactoring, but I don't understand why the `named let` is syntactic sugar - i.e. why it makes the appearance of the code sweeter. To me it makes the code seem more obscure - without `letrec` any reader has to parse the specific syntax of the `let` statement to realise that it is effectively a `letrec`, surely?

Comment: @JamesDuval To a seasoned Schemer, a named `let` is much more readable than a `letrec`. A named `let` works almost like an unnamed `let`, except that it creates a label you can use to jump back (or, if you want, recurse) to the start of the `let`. An explicit `letrec` is best reserved for situations that a named `let` can't handle, such as mutually-recursive functions.

Comment: @JamesDuval I've added a little about it in my answer.

Comment: @JamesDuval Your comments prompted me to write a blog post about named `let`; hope you enjoy! http://dyscour.se/post/58639636506/named-let

Comment: I do; this is really fascinating. I love when I think I've got a handle on the basics and someone shows me how much deeper they really are. I still don't use/haven't investigated macros as much as I should.